# How to list all the dependencies inside an apk virtual package name?

Tags: alpine-linux, apk-tools

deps added to a virtual package:

`apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps gcc make libc-dev`

How can I list them?

`apk list` gives garbage.

```
apk list .build-deps
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.00740ba1.tar.gz: No such file or directory
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.d8b2a6f4.tar.gz: No such file or directory
.build-deps-20191012.021030 noarch {.build-deps} () [installed]
```

not much help from `apk info`

```
apk info .build-deps
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.00740ba1.tar.gz: No such file or directory
WARNING: Ignoring APKINDEX.d8b2a6f4.tar.gz: No such file or directory
.build-deps-20191012.021030 description:
virtual meta package

.build-deps-20191012.021030 webpage:


.build-deps-20191012.021030 installed size:
0
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this command:

```
apk info --depends .build-deps
```

To see all information related to this virtual package, you can use this command:

```
apk info --all .build-deps
```